# Use LINQ to get length of dimensions of Array

Tags: arrays, linq, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I have an array of which I would like to get the length of each dimension stored in an array. I.e. I would like something like the following:

```
Array myArray = //...Blah blah myArray is defined somewhere in code

int[] dimLengths = myArray.SomeLinqStatement...
```

I can do this with some for loop(s) but I was hoping there would be a simple linq statement. So for example, if myArray is a 3D array of 2x3x4 I want dimLengths to be {2, 3, 4}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need LINQ. Here is a simple solution:

```
int[] GetDimensions(Array array)
{
    int[] dimensions = new int[array.Rank];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Rank; i++)
    {
        dimensions[i] = array.GetLength(i);
    }
    return dimensions;
}
```

If you must use LINQ, you could try this, though I am sure the other way is better:

```
int[] dimensions = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank)
                             .Select(i => array.GetLength(i))
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you "sure" the non-linq way is better?

Comment: Experience, plus an understanding of the way LINQ works. The LINQ version does the same thing as the other version, plus two additional operations: It needs to generate a sequence of integers to work on, and it needs to convert an `IEnumerable` to an array. Code with knowledge about the problem is almost always faster than code without that knowledge.

Comment: @KendallFrey: But the difference is negligible(for sure in this case). Then readability should always be preferred.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Always measure it. It is most likely negligible, but you can't tell until you check.

Comment: Why not use method #1 (non-linq) and make it an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need LINQ to get the length of an `Array's dimensions?

```
myArray.GetLength(0); //returns the length of the first dimension
myArray.GetLength(1); //returns the length of the second dimension
myArray.GetLength(2); //returns the length of the third dimension
```

[Array.GetLength Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Here's your "sexy" LINQ approach:

```
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                             { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, array3D.Rank)
      .Select(i => array3D.GetLength(i))
      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Because I want an array of all the dimension lengths. I know I could use a for loop and the GetLength method. I just wanted to do it all on one line with the sexyness of linq :)

Comment: @KrisTrip: Test my other approach.